# Getting value from <input>

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following:

```
<input value="," onchange="refreshDelimiter()" id="delimiter" maxlength="1" style="height: 55px; width: 55px; font-size: 45px;">
```

The function onChange is as follows:

```
function refreshDelimiter(){
    var delimiter = document.getElementById('delimiter').value;
}
```

Issue:
I try the above and it returns - [object HTMLInputElement]
I thought it should return the value entered there? What am I doing wrong yet again?

Comment: I don't see a return statement

Comment: Where does this code "return" anything?

Comment: What are you doing with the value that it gives you that result? There is nothing wrong with the code you have

Comment: I just tried that as well. It's also not working but regardless, the delimiter is actually used later on so whether it returns or not shouldn't be the issue..

Comment: *How* are you using the `delimiter` variable that you get this result?

Comment: the `delimiter` variable is declared in the function `refreshDelimiter()` using it not in the function will be out of scope and undefined

Comment: @SvetoslavAntonov: *"whether it returns or not shouldn't be the issue"* - Except where in the question you describe the problem as: *"it returns - [object HTMLInputElement] I thought it should return the value"*  Can you clarify what specifically you're observing and where/how you're observing it?

Comment: Seems like I commented out the delimiter outside the function, hence the issue... This fixed it, sorry about wasting your time guys.

Answer (score 3):

Use `oninput` instead (which calls the function without waiting for unfocus):

```js
function refreshDelimiter(){
    var delimiter = document.getElementById('delimiter').value;
    console.log(delimiter);    
}
```

```html
<input value="," oninput="refreshDelimiter()" id="delimiter" maxlength="1" style="height: 55px; width: 55px; font-size: 45px;">
```

A better practice would be using `addEventListener` and getting the value of the input inside the function as `this.value`:

```js
delimiter.addEventListener('input', refreshDelimiter);

function refreshDelimiter(){
    var delimiter = this.value;
    console.log(delimiter);    
}
```

```html
<input value="," id="delimiter" maxlength="1" style="height: 55px; width: 55px; font-size: 45px;">
```

Comment: Thanks for that, wasn't related to the issue it seems but good to know.

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain why `oninput` should be used instead of `onchange`, so that this is also useful for other users with similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

you can do several things to solve your problem. Instead of taking input value from element id you can pass the input event to the on change function.

```
<input value="," onchange="refreshDelimiter(event)" id="delimiter" maxlength="1" style="height: 55px; width: 55px; font-size: 45px;">
```

and you can easly access the target on your function like this

```
function refreshDelimiter(e){
    alert(e.target.value)
}
```

another option is you can access the value via getElementById function

```
function refreshDelimiter(){
        var delimiter = document.getElementById('delimiter');
        alert(delimiter.value)
}
```

this will also work too.

Note: onchange function fires when focus leaves the field or if the value has changed since focus was gained

Answer (score -1):

The difference is that the oninput event occurs immediately after the value of an element has changed, while onchange occurs when the element loses focus, after the content has been changed.

Answer (score -1):

you should add return on function call:

```
<input value="," onchange="return refreshDelimiter()" id="delimiter" maxlength="1" style="height: 55px; width: 55px; font-size: 45px;">
```